# Bootstrap dropdown navigation option disappears after click off drowdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I've seen several posts similar to this, but none of the solutions worked. I have a drop-down menu on my navigation. The nav looks like this

```
<ul>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a href="insurance.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Insurance <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="insurance.html">Insurance</a></li>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="boat.html">Boat</a></li>
        <li><a href="medical.html">Health</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navdivider"></li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="customer-service.html">Customer Service</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navdivider"></li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="claims.html">Claims</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

When I click on the drop-down menu it shows up fine. When I click out of it or click the `'Insurance'` link on the navigation the option on the navigation disappears. I get

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
   <a href="insurance.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
```

I've seen this same error posted elsewhere and I'm aware that it is a conflict with jquery & bootstrap, but I can't seem to fix it using the suggested fixes. I am not trained in javascript, so I'm unsure if I implemented incorrectly. Thank you.

Comment: do you have bootstrap .js linked above the closing </body> tag?

Comment: I tried that, and then the drop down did not work--the link went directly to insurance.html

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3.2.0. When I try to upgrade to 3.3.7 I get the same error as above (no dropdown).    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: could you post the entire html for the page, either here or on https://jsfiddle.net/ ?